# How to link library to compile/install a Perl module manually?

Tags: perl, build, module, manual

I want to compile/install a Perl module that depends on a library that is not in Strawberry Perl 5.12. I used Strawberry on a Windows box to install the module (Net-SSH2). The installation failed because it requires the library (libssh2). My issue is similar to this guy's http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=814455. But I cannot use that solution because it does not apply to my Perl version and more important, I have very restricted Internet connection.

I downloaded the libssh2 library, but I don't know how specify the include path in the Makefile.PL so I can run:

```
perl Makefile.PL
make 
make install
```

I appreciate any help or pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Net::SSH2 is included in [latest beta of Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/beta/). Another option is to [unpack this archive into Strawberry's directory](http://strawberryperl.com/package/kmx/32_libs/32bit_libssh2-1.2.5-bin_20100520.zip).

Answer (score 2):

Edit your `Makefile.PL` and add or edit the `INC` and/or `LIBS` parameters in the `WriteMakefile` call. See [the `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#Using_Attributes_and_Parameters) for the expected format. These will be passed to the compiler and linker.

Comment: No file editing necessary, these also work on the command line: `perl Makefile.PL INC=… LIBS=…`